# How to get "Traffic" on StackEgg?

Tags: stack-egg

I've graduated my site on StackEgg, and now a new stat called "Traffic" appeared alongside the other four.

However, whatever I do, it doesn't seem to gain hearts.

What am I missing?

Comment: I was going to migrate this to Meta, but then realized that it's technically a question about a video game AND about our engine, so it's on-topic for either.  :)

Comment: Do what I did: close it when you have some questions and quality, and the traffic will grow. I don't know if this is the right way, but it worked! I came back with only 2 hearts missing (1 on quality and 1 on answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of traffic goes up or down by a certain amount each day, depending on the displayed value for Quality and Answers:

```
                      Answers
        |  -1  |   0  |   1  |   2  |   3  |   4  
  ——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————
    -1  | -0.8 | -0.8 | -0.8 | -0.5 | -0.4 | -0.2 
Q ——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————
u    0  | -0.8 | -0.8 | -0.8 | -0.5 | -0.4 | -0.2 
a ——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————
l    1  | -0.8 | -0.8 | -0.8 | -0.5 | -0.4 | -0.2 
i ——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————
t    2  | -0.5 | -0.5 | -0.5 | -0.2 | -0.1 |  0.1 
y ——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————
     3  | -0.4 | -0.4 | -0.4 | -0.1 |  0.0 |  0.2 
  ——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————+——————
     4  | -0.2 | -0.2 | -0.2 |  0.1 |  0.2 |  0.4
```

<sup>`-1` means red/critical</sup>

So Answers plus Quality has to be greater than six to at least break even.

Answer (score 10):

From the description of "Answer"

> Posting answers is what your Site's life is all about. Only with many
>   answers (and high quality!) can it attract traffic.

- 4 Answer + 4 Quality next Round -> Answer -> Still no traffic
- 2nd Answer -> 1 Traffic

Also not completely true the above the following just happened:

- 3/3/2/3/1 -> Question -> +1 Traffic
- 3/3/2/3/2 -> Question -> +1 Traffic

So Questions can attract traffic too.

Comment: From what I've seen, it's not the action you take, but the values of the Answers and Quality stats that drive traffic.

Comment: @user2357112 *In order for your Site's traffic to grow (and not shrink again!), it must consistently offer lots of good help to the world – and that means continuously keeping both its answers and its quality high.*